# Access denied for user root@localhost on Ubuntu and OS X

Tags: mysql, pdo, xampp, access-denied

I'm developing a web application and it is working just fine in Windows, but now I'm trying to run it in Ubuntu and in a Macbook and it's giving me a Access denied error.

The error doesn't allow me to retrieve information from the database, but let me enter the web application.

I can access to localhost/myApplication, but can't retrieve the database info.

The thing is that I can access the database if I change my code's hostname to 127.0.0.1, but I don't want to do that, I want to keep it as localhost.

I've tried everything I found around Internet, like:

I've changed my hosts file to listen to 127.0.0.1 localhost. I've granted all privileges to my user and flushed them. I've uninstalled and reinstalled Xampp and MySQL. I've changed my.cnf, php.ini, socket location and any other config files inside Xampp folder, but nothing worked.

The error it gives me and my code:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

My code:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb", $db_user, $db_pass);
$conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

I know that if I change localhost to 127.0.0.1 I can have access, but I want to keep it as localhost because I don't want to change all my other applications to listen to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Check your HOSTS file on the UBUNTU system. Make sure there is a `127.0.0.1  localhost` line in there

Comment: Then !!! Did you put a password on the `root` account,,,, and does it match what you have in your Windows version of MySQL

Comment: Is the `root` account allowed to be accessed from `localhost` it obviously is from `127.0.0.1` but did you add an account that is legal from `localhost`

Comment: Yes, I have a `127.0.0.1 localhost` line in my Ubuntu and OS X systems.

And yes, I have the same root password in the three systems MySQL installations, also have granted all privileges to root and every other user.

Comment: _Small Note_ The HOSTS file does not cause anything to listen on anything. It is like ADDING a DNS A record. All it does is associate `localhost` with the ip address `127.0.0.1`

Comment: After adding `127.0.0.1 localhost` to your HOSTS file, did you reboot, or refresh the local DNS Cache

Comment: I had rebooted plenty of times, also created two root users: `root@localhost` and `root@%` with the same passwords and privileges, but nothing helped. I have the same error trying to access the database information within my application.

The weird thing is that I don't have that error if I change my code's host to 127.0.0.1, but I don't want to do that.